# Override BeanDefinition's beanClassName in an BeanFactoryPostProcessor

Tags: spring

as some springframeworks components install their own BeanDefinitionParsers a lot of bean definitons are made by these parses.

but sometimes all I want is to override just the class name of an BeanDefinition created by such a BeanDefinitionParser (to instantiate a subclass of the default class the parser did create; for small behaviour modification).

Sadly springframework only seems to have PropertyOverrideConfigurer which enables you to override the properties of a BeanDefinition.

Why doens't have the spring framework something similar like PropertyOverrideConfigurer but for overriding a BeanDefinition's beanClassName.

Would that be an sensible extension to the default classes in the spring framework.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at `org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`

```
@Configuration
public class ClassOverrideBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {

  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
    BeanDefinition definitionToOverride= registry.getBeanDefinition("yourBeanName");
    if (definitionToOverrideinstanceof AbstractBeanDefinition) {
      ((AbstractBeanDefinition) definitionToOverride).setBeanClass(YourChildClassWithExtendedBehavior.class);
    } else { //you can eliminate one of the branches depending on your case
      definitionToOverride.setBeanClassName("com.example.demo.YourChildClassWithExtendedBehavior");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
    //DO NOTHING
  }

}
```